# NSDictionary Error Handling

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, error-handling, nserror

I am creating this application but I don't know how to handle the error when there is no value for a given entry in the NSDictionary. Here is the code that I have currently:

```
   NSDictionary *entry = [self entries][indexPath.row];
    NSDictionary *text = [self entries][indexPath.row];
    NSString *user = entry[@"user"][@"full_name"];
    NSString *caption = text[@"caption"][@"text"];

    if (caption != nil && entry != [NSNull null] && text != nil && caption != [NSNull null]) {
        RNBlurModalView *modal = [[RNBlurModalView alloc] initWithViewController:self title:user message:caption];
        [modal show];
    }
```

Here is the error response I receive when I tap on a cell without any caption:

```
2013-08-08 02:36:57.871 Floadt[5566:c07] -[NSNull objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x310b678
2013-08-08 02:36:57.872 Floadt[5566:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x310b678'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2fda012 0x260be7e 0x30654bd 0x2fc9bbc 0x2fc994e 0x5606b 0x1c7a42f 0x1c8c182 0x1c8c394 0x261f705 0x188693c 0x18869ac 0x261f705 0x188693c 0x18869ac 0x1a401d3 0x2fa2afe 0x2fa2a3d 0x2f807c2 0x2f7ff44 0x2f7fe1b 0x2bb77e3 0x2bb7668 0x1778ffc 0x2d2d 0x2c55)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: can you share the structure of your dictionary?

Comment: Superfluous... Everything is superfluous in your error checking, Objective-C is not Java, you don't have to check for `nil`. You left out **the essence,** though: `if ([entry isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])` and `if ([text isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])`

Comment: where would those lines go with my code above @H2CO3

Comment: @prnk28 The first one before the first line, the second one before the second line.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear why `entry` and `text` are the same thing. That could be a typo that is causing you issues:

```
NSDictionary *entry = [self entries][indexPath.row];
NSDictionary *text = [self entries][indexPath.row];
```

Then, you should really use `isEqual` for your equality checks (even if only to prevent you getting into bad habits) and check the obtained values (you don't currently check `user`):

```
if (![user isEqual:[NSNull null]] && ![caption isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
```

Your current checks are mostly redundant - you need to check things before you use them, not afterwards. Checking `entry` and `text` must be done earlier. Then check `user` and `caption`.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using two `NSDictionary` though they store same value `[self entries][indexPath.row]?`

Change your checking as follow

```
if (!caption && ([entry isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) && ([text isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]))
```